# "A certain thread back in June"

Tags: support, moderation

*First off, sorry, this is more of a direct question for the mods than meta, but I don't know how else to reach them.*

I recently conversed with Stack Overflow employees about a suspension last year on this site. Topic aside, this is a quote from their message:

> Right now, you have about 11 months. Maybe a little less, **if I count a certain thread back in June that only got you a warning** - but suspension-wise, 11 months.

I have no idea what they are talking about. In my mind (and that is obviously very subjective) I posted very little and only petty, stupid questions and answers since my suspension. Nothing controversial (I would call it interesting) at all. So I looked through my global inbox and found nothing there. No controversial posts and certainly no warning.

I have asked them directly what they meant, but they did not reply.

So... what were they talking about? What "warning" did I get in June? I guess we *both* have a hard time believing I got a warning *and stayed completely silent about it*. I don't think I deleted stuff from my inbox, not sure if that is even possible, I don't think I ever tried.

I don't mind (and frankly don't care) if I got a warning. I left here for a reason, if I got a warning and it was justified, so be it. But I don't remember any, the logs available to me don't say anything about it either.

So can you shed any light on that?

*As always: I brought it up here, feel free to post whatever you feel is needed to answer my question, please err on the side of too much information, you can sell my privacy on ebay to the highest bidder as long as I get to know what people are talking about.*

Comment: Hi nvoigt--off the top of my head I don't recall (because I'm a Bear of Very Little Brain) so I'll have to do some digging around. But I wanted to quickly let you know that this is a fine channel to use. (The "Contact Us" link and pinging us in [chat] are the other easy ways to catch our attention.)

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did a bit of digging. Based on following the same kinds of breadcrumbs that the Community Managers (CMs) would see in the moderation records on an account, my guess is it's referring to the flag and verbal warning in June 2017 that resulted from the 23 deleted comments on [this deleted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/102336) (link is 10k+ rep only). It's the right time and kind of event to fit the implied reference in

> Maybe a little less, if I count a certain thread back in June that only got you a warning

Basically, it was a repeat of the same things that lead to the previous suspension, but our lack of hair-trigger to re-suspend for new offences resulted in it only getting an informal warning. (Sometimes that's enough of a touch to head off a return to a previous problem.) It didn't also get recorded as an official annotation. Depending on context around that CM quote you've provided us, I can understand how that might not be seen as fully counting, but still meriting mentioning, in relation to the reason for the April suspension.

Comment: That occasion is my best guess as well. The comment argument got a bit heated, and I read the comment warning left behind being nonspecific to just nvoigt.

Comment: Ha, that post does not pop up in my log. Funny. Okay, that makes sense. I don't remember what exactly was said there, but that's good enough, now at least I know what the point of that remark was. Thanks!

Comment: @nvoigt If you head to [your list of answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/7665/nvoigt?tab=answers) there will be a "deleted recent answers" link in the bottom left. It might show up there along with some others. (Though I'm not sure how recent "recent" is, given we're also talking a timeframe of nearly a year.)

Answer (score 3):

Upon review of your account, your annotations and warnings seem to stop with the suspension last April.  There’s nothing annotated on your account since then on this site (I can’t speak for other sites or other accounts).  It’s possible someone said something vaguely disciplinary in a comment somewhere since, but that’s harder to track down.  You might consider asking them what they mean...  but from a site mod perspective there’s nothing obvious.